# How to catch a new chat message in an app using Quickblox (outside of the ChatView)?

Tags: quickblox

Using Quickblox it is very easy to send and receive messages when you're in the chat view. But what happens when you're not in the chat view and you receive a message? What is the best way to catch that new chat message in the app?

- should I use notifications and rely on the appDelegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification? Or is there another way? (As I understand, remote notifications can be slower and less reliable than the chat itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can use push notifications, if you are not in the chat.
Please find needed here http://quickblox.com/modules/messages/