# Quickblox: update chat dialog list whenever new messages are received

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

Im working with quickBlox server for chatting. I have a chatList Controller which displays List of all dialogs. And ChatController, which will displays chat in particular dialog.

Chatting in group and one-to-one is working fine...

Now, When Im on chatList page, and receive message in any dialog, I want to update some data in chatList. SO how to capture the received message event in chatList VC.

Also, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is called when a message is received. But updating dialog from here takes some time, which is not user friendly.

Is there any way to detect a message arrived on chatlist page itself???

**Edit 1:** I have found that one way is to create a push notification: [From This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466390/how-to-catch-a-new-chat-message-in-an-app-using-quickblox-outside-of-the-chatvi?rq=1).  But im not getting how to do that.

Thanks in Advance..